# Suggested web authentication for a mobile app api?

Tags: android, zend-framework, rest, web

I am building a REST based api for my Android app. I use access tokens and basic header authentication currently. Any suggestions to improve the authentication process?

Comment: depends on tons of parameters. are you connecting with any social network? do you want to let users connect with external accounts, like oauth?

Comment: I have my own apis, I want to ensure that the calls are coming only from my app

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the OAuth protocol to manage API authentication. You can read more about this protocol here: http://oauth.net/.

Answer (score 0):

+1 ezimuel - "OAuth" is an excellent suggestion.

However, I was surprised to see the link [Getting Started with the Tasks API and OAuth 2.0 on Android](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android) was deprecated.

Please check out these links:

- Google Play Authorization: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html (also uses OAuth 2.0)
- Authenticating to OAuth 2.0 Services: http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html
- OAuth and REST in Android (1): http://simpleprogrammer.com/2011/05/25/oauth-and-rest-in-android-part-1/
- OAuth and REST in Android (2): http://simpleprogrammer.com/2011/06/04/oauth-and-rest-in-android-part-2/